# PHP JQuery - Multiple fields post

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am looking for any advice on how to do this, the concept is confusing me. I am not looking for an exact solution, just help with the logic.

I have a HTML form that is like this:

| Name | Price | Comment

Which I then pass to PHP script that updates this as a record inside the database.
The problem being is that, I am going going to be creating multiple entries (through JQuery) and I don't know how to pass these as one through to the PHP file. I know that I can do this:

```
<input type="name" id="name[]" value="" />
```

And handle each of the posts as an array, and, I can do this for all of the fields inside the form. But is there an efficient way to link them all up?

For example:

If I have 5 new rows then the array is going to be:

```
$_POST['names'] = {"name1", "name2", "name3", ...}
$_POST['cost'] = {"cost1", "cost2", "cost3", ...}
$_POST['comments'] = {"comment1", "comment2", "comment3", ...}
```

I hope that this makes sense and someone can help me!

Comment: What do you mean by "linked them all up"? Do you mean before you send them to the server, or after?

Comment: @Jez - After.. I need to associate each of the rows in the form, with each other and then update them to the database

Comment: @LelioFaieta It is generally true that the fields will be ordered according to their order, but it is not guaranteed as it is not specified in HTTP specification. So if PHP suddenly decides to make GET variables an unsorted Map (of course this is unlikely to happen), then order is not guaranteed. Another variable is how the browser submits multivalued variables... Again, it's an unspoken rule, but not written down as a standard.

Comment: I rely on jquey serialize method that put them in the correct order in the array iterating trhough the DOM. I agree with you about HTTP and the possibility of a mx up of the array. Let's say that what @Barmar has written in his answer is what I use to do too.

Comment: @Populus If PHP ever changed like that it would break thousands of scripts. Everyone with rows of multiple `XXX[]` fields in their forms depends on all the fields being in sync (except for checkboxes, which are a known issue because only the checked ones get submitted).

Comment: @LelioFaieta I've deleted my answer, I think I misunderstood the question. When he said he's using jQuery, I thought he meant jQuery AJAX to submit the form. Now that I reread, I think he's using it to construct the form and wants to know how to do that.

Comment: @Barmar I had the same idea reading it and answering in my first comment. Deleting too!

Comment: @Barmar Yea, as I said in brackets, it likely won't happen. But because of the lack of clarity, we should not assume something works a certain way. E.g. PHP associated arrays are ordered maps, and it's stated in the documentation now, but that wasn't always the case (the documentation part). In the case of HTTP GET and POST ordering, ordering of multivalued parameters is not mentioned. The obvious and logical way is to order it according to whichever is first, and it's the unofficial standard. Should we rely on that? Yes and no. I would prefer if it's actually written into the standard.

Comment: Also, most people write code while making assumptions, and those assumptions *may* not always be true. That doesn't mean its bad to make assumptions, but it does mean you have to take the consequences of making them.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done with HTML alone, and all your values will be structured even better than you suggest.

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <input name="rows[0][name]"/>
        <input name="rows[0][price]"/>
        <input name="rows[0][comment]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input name="rows[1][name]"/>
        <input name="rows[1][price]"/>
        <input name="rows[1][comment]"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then in PHP access `$_REQUEST['rows']` and see its contents.

Comment: Was typing my answer up and generally the same as yours. The only extra comment to make is that OP's code has a typo (or not), where the bracket notation is in the `id` attribute instead of the `name`.

Comment: I could be wrong but this is under the assumption that the OP's PHP settings are using registered globals which is wildly insecure correct. I highly advise against this...

Comment: The only disadvantage to this is that if you have a great amount of rows there will be a lot of wasted bytes, but let's be real here, nobody cares about traffic anyway :D

Comment: @War10ck AFAIK from some version of php register_globals is always turned on and cannot be turned off.

Comment: @php_nub_qq The [default for registered globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) changed from on to off in version 4.2.0. `register_globals` was then deprecated in 5.3.0 and removed in 5.4.0. It definitely should not be relied on...

Comment: @War10ck I think there is some confusion here. The option to turn the globals off is removed, how does that make using globals unreliable? The only occasion where this would not work is if the request is sent without the content type being xxx-form-urlencoded or the request body is invalid, but I believe that is unlikely to happen.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Sorry, I may have caused the confusion. Globals in general are not unreliable. The idea that when the form is sent to the server via `GET` or `POST`, or whatever that the `$rows` variable is created automatically has been removed. This is what the `register_globals` directive did for you automatically resulting in a security flaw. For this reason, it was changed to default to off, deprecated and then removed. You'll have access to it via the method type properties (i.e. `$_GET['rows'][0][name]` or `$_POST['rows'][0]['name']` but not simply as `$rows`).

Comment: @War10ck Oh, Jesus! I'm such a retard. Apologies for my incompetence, I didn't even notice I had written `$rows`.